# Spring: mocking security enhanced service

Tags: spring, spring-security, mockito, spring-aop, spring-test

We'are imlementing part of our security at service layer, so I add `@PreAuthorize` annotation to some methods of `MyService`.

At `MyServiceSecurityTest` I want to test only security role-permission matrix, without any business logic. For that reason I have to mock `MyService`. the problem is that both Mockito and Spring security use CGLIB proxies, and my service is not enhanced with `@PreAuthorize` after `Mockito.mock(MyService.class)`.

*Is there any way to mock service and preserve `@PreAuthorize` logic?*

---

Example:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements IMyService {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SYSOP')")
    public void someMethod(ComplexDTO dto) {
        // lots of logic and dependencies, require lots of stubbing.
    }
}
```

In order to avoid initialization of all dependencies of `MyService#someMethod` and building `ComplexDTO` at `MyServiceSecurityTest` I want to mock `MyServiceSecurityTest` but preserve `@PreAuthorize` checks.

Comment: Other simple way is just override your service method that you don't want to test.

Comment: @cosmos I'm not familiar with `@MockBean`. I've just replaced `@Mock MyService service` with `@MockBean MyService service` and have the same result. Do I missed something? Why do you believe it will help?

Comment: @cosmos I do not need override anything. I want to test all methods

Comment: @cosmos I need to mock and  test `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SYSOP')") public void someMethod() { ... }`

Comment: Why don't you put whole class that you want to test in question and remove logic that you don't want to show it to public. That way it'll be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: @dur no, as I understand `@PreAuthorize` annotation will not work on interface level, and I have to declare security at implementation level and force CGLIB proxying.

Comment: @dur wow! You're right, didn't know that. Maybe I've read obsolete articles. I will try this during next few hours. Anycase, thank you a lot!

Comment: @dur even after moving annotations to interface level, mockito proxy lack security checks.

Comment: @dur MockBean didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You need to do integration tests and not unit tests.  In general, you do not see mock classes in integration tests, at least you would not mock the class you are testing, in this I case I guess its the `MyService` class.

Setting up integration tests involves reading up on, but the short example below should get you on the right path

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("myProfile")
public class MyServiceIT {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testMyService() {
        logger.info("testMyService");

        //user TestRestTemplate to call your service.
    }

}
```

EDIT:  In this integration test, Spring boots up normally.  That means all the annotations for security are processed and all the beans it needs to create are created and properly injected.  One thing you may have to control is the Spring profile.... that can be done with the `@ActiveProfiles("myProfile")` annotation, which I just added to the example.

Comment: that's the option I'm trying to avoid. If I will test in your way - I have to test both - security and business logic of `MyService` at one place

Comment: I start to think that very few people faced this problem.  And there is no fancy solution. That can mean that it's wrong approach - cover service-security with that kind of tests

Comment: in other hand, suppose your service perform really heavyweight logic. One method run takes 10-30 seconds. Now you have about 30 roles, you want to test each method against each role. It will take pretty much time.

Comment: Can you short circuit the logic?  I hate baking test scenarios into the business logic, but maybe if it is done elegantly it might not be too scornful.

Comment: I just mean that at common integration test you gonna test each endpoint against let say few cases. If you gonna test security - number of test invocations will be multiplied by number of roles/authorities. But integration test is pretty heavy-weight thing. I don't know how business logic will help here (

Comment: In the past we used to create an interface for all our service classes.  Then we would do an impl for it.  What if you do the same and you can have an impl that just has the security annotations, then inject that blank security impl of your service interface?

Comment: yeah, I thought about that option. But it may be an overhead to create separate class for each service just for test purposes. I even not sure if I have to test security that way